# Embedding an image in PDF attachment using html tags and Blob.toPdf()

Tags: pdf, blob

I want to add an image to a pdf I am creating and attach it to an email that I send via apex code. I am using html and Blob.toPdf() to make the pdf. I saw this post regarding Blob.toPdf()'s limitations on images: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000123577&language=en_US. It says:

> To work around this Blob.toPdf()'s limitation you may resort to one of
>   the below approaches:
>
> 1. Store the image as a static resource and then use it in code.
> 2. Use a Visual Force Page and render it as pdf

So I tried both ways, the first one throws an error: "An error occurred while parsing the input string" (which happens with  tag no matter what src I use).

And the second way is not an option for me cause I have to get the page content that I'm rendering as pdf and attach it to my email BUT "Page.getContent() does not work in Triggers or Email Services".

Is there any work around for this limitations?

Comment: As an FYI, Visualforce pages with embedded PDFs won't render as PDFs.